# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo exec-maven-plugin (in the book mahout in action)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, mahout, netbeans-8

I am learning Mahout and studying the example code in the book *Mahout in Action* by Sean Owen et al., Manning Publications, 2012. The download link for all example codes is https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/6/f732418-aa9b-4e84-86d1-e49b5e782423/MiA_SourceCode.zip

When I run every code in the project on NetBeans 8.0.2, e.g. RecommenderIntro.java in the folder mia.recommender.ch02. It says

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec  (default-cli) on project mia: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/fdfdfd/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jcl/1.6.0/slf4j-jcl-1.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/fdfdfd/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.11/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: intro.csv
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.<init>(FileDataModel.java:160)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.<init>(FileDataModel.java:146)
    at mia.recommender.ch02.RecommenderIntro.main(RecommenderIntro.java:21)
```

Hopefully you could help me spot the error in the code. Thank you!!

Comment: This doesn't say what the error is. What you quote just says 'an error happened'. The code and book are now years out of date but should still compile

Comment: I changed DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("intro.csv")); to a absolute path DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("c:\\...\\intro.csv"), then it's ok. Thank you.

Comment: I have now quoted the right part in my post.